# Java Scanner Take Input, call a method, then back to read more input not working

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I have a class called `PlayGame`, and in the `main` method I have this chunk of code:

```
public class PlayGame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Where would you like your adventure to begin? (Enter a number)\n");
            System.out.println("1. Play the Game\n2. Quit the Game");
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            String userAction;
            try {
                userAction = userInput.nextLine().trim();
                if (userAction.equals("1")) {
                    pressPlay();
                } else if (userAction.equals("2")) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, your selection wasn't valid.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is all fine, and when the user types **1**, `pressPlay()` is called and it proceeds to the next method which does some stuff, mainly printing things to the screen. However, when I leave the `pressPlay()` method and return back to this main method, I start getting errors for reading the Input:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
    at PlayGame.main(PlayGame.java:17)
```

Can you clue me in into how I can get around this? Much appreciated!

**EDIT** - I just want it to return to the while loop in the main method and ask for 1 or 2 again, and take a valid 1 or 2. My code goes all the way through to `userAction = userInput.nextLine().trim();` without waiting for anymore user input the second time round, after leaving the `pressPlay()` method.

**EDIT** - The `pressPlay()` method produces a grid that the player is able to move around in by typing particular commands. It has a `while (true) {` loop inside of it, as well as `Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);` which takes the players input. If the player types quit, it calls a break out of the while loop and returns back to the main method, where the problem then arises.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: That part of the code does, yes. It's after you go to pressPlay() and back again that it breaks. I'll post an edit with a description of what the pressPlay() class does to try and pinpoint if the error is in there.

Comment: Did You break from the while loop that inside the `pressPlay()`

Comment: Yeah, if the player types quit, it calls a break out of the while loop in `pressPlay()` and returns back to the main method

Comment: Try to use the scanner and read integers only with `NextInt()` and see it will works fine or not? i feel the problem in `nextLine().trim()`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Try add this `Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);` out side the while loop

Comment: Nope, still doesn't solve it :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24997/discussion-between-jamie-and-hossam)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to fix the issue.

In both my main method and my `pressPlay()` method, I was creating separate scanners taking input from `System.in`, and this was causing problems as it would no longer take input from the main method. Instead I took the Scanner out of the main method and put it after `public class PlayGame {`, and used this same scanner in both of my methods, rather than separate ones.

Thank you Jayamohan and Hossam for your input (: