# What would cause a Scanner to throw a NoSuchElementException when returning to a while loop from a method call?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

Relevant section of code:

```
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in); //to get user input
while(!close) { //program will keep prompting user for selection until they close it
    System.out.println(menu); //prints the menu
    selection = kbd.nextLine(); //gets the menu selection from the user
```

This only happens when returning to the while loop from a method call, if I return from an if statement with no method call no error occurs. Here is the error message in full:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
at class.main(class.java:29)
```

The line it points to is the `selection = kbd.nextLine();` line.

Comment: Any point of creating a new Scanner on every loop iteration? Try moving it outside the loop.

Comment: Tried moving it to the top of main, but I get the exact same error pointing to the same line

Comment: @Spork is it possible to post the complete code?

Comment: Can you have a space in between `Scanner` and `(System.in)`? As in, is that valid syntax?

Comment: @Spork how are you giving the file path from console? What is your input?

Comment: @arin1405 just a standard windows filepath, i.e. C:\users\...\file.txt

Comment: @Yann4 not sure but fixing it still throws the same error

Comment: You mention file path but your code is for console input... Can you clarify that?

Comment: @Spork did you try something like `"C:\\users\\...\\file.txt"`?

Comment: @arin1405 found the issue below! thanks for the troubleshooting help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue here!

[Java Scanner Take Input, call a method, then back to read more input not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036445/java-scanner-take-input-call-a-method-then-back-to-read-more-input-not-working?rq=1)

Turns out other instances of scanner in my methods were causing an issue with the scanner in main. Moving the scanner to the top of the class resolved this issue!

Answer (score 0):

@Spork
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in); //to get user input

```
while(!close) { //program will keep prompting user for selection until they close it
  System.out.println(menu); //prints the menu
  if(kbd.hasNextLine(){
      selection = kbd.nextLine(); //gets the menu selection from the user
  }
}
```

let me know if it helps.